# JWT with Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2, json-web-token

I have created the Spring Authorization Server which issues JWT-s and a Resource Server which checks the JWT, its claims and permissions on the Authorization Server. To do so, I have followed this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt).

My question is why I need to send the `Authorization` header with HTTP Basic authorization and Base64 encoded username/password (ClientId:ClientSecret) in get token request? I have seen JWT implementations where only username and password are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the specification, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3):

> **2.3 Client Authentication**
>
> If the client type is confidential, the client and authorization server establish a client authentication method suitable for the security requirements of the authorization server.  The authorization server MAY accept any form of client authentication meeting its security requirements.
>
> Confidential clients are typically issued (or establish) a set of client credentials used for authenticating with the authorization server (e.g., password, public/private key pair).
>
> The authorization server MAY establish a client authentication method with public clients.  However, the authorization server MUST NOT rely on public client authentication for the purpose of identifying the client.
>
> The client MUST NOT use more than one authentication method in each  request.

By default Spring Security OAuth 2.0 protects the token endpoint, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> The token endpoint is protected for you by default by Spring OAuth in the `@Configuration` support using HTTP Basic authentication of the client secret.

But it seems, that you can disable the client authentication:

- [Spring Security OAuth 2.0 - client secret always required for authorization code grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785628/spring-security-oauth-2-0-client-secret-always-required-for-authorization-code)
- [Is it possible to get an access_token from Spring OAuth2 server without client secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356590/is-it-possible-to-get-an-access-token-from-spring-oauth2-server-without-client-s)
- [Spring Security OAuth 2.0 with no client_secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890255/spring-security-oauth-with-no-client-secret)

Answer (score 0):

That is the structure of the JWT token:

```
HMACSHA256(
      base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
      base64UrlEncode(payload),
    secret

    )


As you are doing a JWT implementation all the 3 parts must be there: header.payload.secret
```

Maybe in the implementation you have seen - the server was working with Default Secret